# How do I automatically show the first result of this menu?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this menu, when entering my site it only shows the content that has in the menu "Movies" if I click on the menu, when I enter the site it shows nothing, and I wanted the opposite of that, that he would display the contents of the "Movies" menu without having to click on it, what did I do wrong?

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Filmes')">Filmes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Series')">Séries</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Animes')">Animes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Desenhos')">Desenhos</button>
</div>

<div id="Filmes" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Filmes</h3>
  <p>Todos os filmes</p>
</div>

<div id="Series" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Séries</h3>
  <p>Todas as séries</p>
</div>

<div id="Animes" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Animes</h3>
  <p>Todos os animes</p>
</div>

<div id="Desenhos" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Desenhos</h3>
  <p>Todos os desenhos</p>
</div>
```

Comment: code sample mate

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to post the code but it only gave error, I posted in the pastebin also could not send here, but here it is https://pastebin.com/KKF85Uqc

Comment: @Nae 
the example above, note that the "Filmes" menu does not display any content, just by clicking on it

Comment: So you want the first tab, "Filmes", to be active/preselected?

Comment: @Ricky 
yes, it is activated without clicking on it, and when you click on another menu it disappears and shows the menu clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might be what you're looking for.  Basically, I changed the initial class of the `Filmes` button to include `active` and additionally made sure the `Filmes` section included a `display: block` in its style.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'Filmes')">Filmes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Series')">Séries</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Animes')">Animes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Desenhos')">Desenhos</button>
</div>

<div style="display: block" id="Filmes" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Filmes</h3>
  <p>Todos os filmes</p>
</div>

<div id="Series" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Séries</h3>
  <p>Todas as séries</p>
</div>

<div id="Animes" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Animes</h3>
  <p>Todos os animes</p>
</div>

<div id="Desenhos" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Desenhos</h3>
  <p>Todos os desenhos</p>
</div>
```